# How to use NFC API with google chrome for android

Tags: android, api, google-chrome, nfc

The beta version of Google's Chrome web browser for Android requests user permission to control near field communication features. How is-it possible to communicate with tags from web-based apps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently no API for this. Consider implementing NFC features in Java and using a WebView for your UI, though at the moment the WebView is Android Browser (not Chrome for Android).

Comment: Thank you, I hope it will be possible one day.

Comment: Is there an API for this yet ?

Comment: Chrome feature related to this topic currently is in development. More information can be found here: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6261030015467520